# MAUI (Blazor Hybrid) set minimum window size on windows .NET6

Tags: maui, blazor-hybrid

I want to define a minimum window size - or to be more precise client size - for my blazor hybrid application. The user should not be able to make the window smaller than a certain size.

So far I have tried the following:

```
 builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
    {
      events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
      {
        wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
        {
          var nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
          var win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
          var winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);

          if (winuiAppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
          {
            p.Maximize();
            p.IsResizable = true;
            p.IsMaximizable = true;
            p.IsMinimizable = true;
          }

          window.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        });
      });
    });
```

```
 private static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    const int minWidth = 800;
    const int minHeight = 600;

    var nativeWindowHandle = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(sender);
    var win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
    var winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);

    if (winuiAppWindow.ClientSize.Width < minWidth || winuiAppWindow.ClientSize.Height < minHeight)
    {
      int width = winuiAppWindow.ClientSize.Width;
      int height = winuiAppWindow.ClientSize.Height; 

      winuiAppWindow.ResizeClient(new SizeInt32(width < minWidth ? minWidth : width, height < minHeight ? minHeight : height));
    }
  }
```

This code works when I resize the height of the client. If I try to resize the width of the client to height starts to grow by - in my case by 31 - every time I resize the client smaller than the minimum size.

Comment: For this, you can check this issue : [How to specify a fixed size for the application window? (.NET MAUI Blazor WinUI)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/2370#discussioncomment-2630819).